# Does Instagram have a developer API for accessing a user’s saved posts?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Once authenticated as a user, using an Instagram developer API, can you get the user’s saved media?

Comment: I wish they did, but I don't think they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Instagram does not have such an API.

Answer (score -3):

Yes they do. Please see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started)

Comment: The links don't actually point to getting saved posts.